# Radix sort python grammar

Tags: python, sorting, radix

Find a radix sort code, but couldn't understand well for line "arr=[j for i in bucket_list for j in i]"
I know it's sorting based on the bucket_list, but what j, i means in this line and what's the general way to write this function? Thanks.

```
def radix_sort(arr:List[int]):
    n = len(str(max(arr)))  
    for k in range(n):
        bucket_list=[[] for i in range(10)]
        for i in arr:
            bucket_list[i//(10**k)%10].append(i)
        arr=[j for i in bucket_list for j in i]
        print(arr)
    return arr
```

Comment: It's flattening a list of lists to a list e.g. `bucket_list = [[1, 2], [5, 6], [3]]` => `arr = [1, 2, 5, 6, 3]`

Comment: Please see https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Comment: Yes, whatever Nick has said is the answer, also i have expained it below, you can refer.

Comment: Thanks all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code you're asking about has a list comprehension in it. It's equivalent to a two-level nested loop:

```
arr = []
for i in bucket_list:
    for j in i:
        arr.append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

So as it is a radix sort,
In any iteration we can have 1 or more values of the same weights:
Take an example of 456 and 656, let's say we are seeing the unit digit, so in the buckets, these two will be coming inside a list, i.e. like [[456, 656]], even in the second iteration as both are 56, they will come in the same bucket [[456, 656]].

```
 arr=[j for i in bucket_list for j in i]
```

So want this line does, is its taking the inside elements of each bucket in the same order they are placed.